# execv, select and read

Tags: c++, c, unix

I am creating a child-parent `fork()` to be able to communicate with a shell(`/bin/sh`) from the parent through a pipe.

The problem is:
In a parent I set a `select()` on a child output, but it unblocks only when the process is finished! So when I run say `ps` it's okay. but when I run `/bin/sh` it does not output until shell exits. But I want to read it's output!

```
for(;;) {
select(PARENT_READ+1,&sh,NULL,NULL,NULL); // This unblocks only when shell exits!
if (FD_ISSET(PARENT_READ,&sh)) {
   while (n = read (PARENT_READ, &buf,30)) {
       buf[30]='\0';
       printf("C: %s\n",buf);
   };
};
}
```

The answer is somewhere in the field of disabling buffering of pipes?

Comment: With what arguments are you `exec()`-ing the shell?  How are you providing it a pipe?  Are these `pipe()` pipes or something else?

Comment: File descriptors do not have buffering. `/bin/sh` might be simply waiting for you input - before sending anything back.

Comment: 1) I do an execv/execve of /bin/sh 2) pipe() is a pipe, yes.

Comment: @Dummy00001: It should at least send the '$' symbol and afterall I am sending it commands like 'touch test' and they are executed fine as I can see the files being created.

Comment: @JAmes: `$` (the `$PS1`) is printed for interactive shells. Shell's input is not terminal == non-interactive shell. `touch test` doesn't produce any output. Tried `echo hello world`?

Comment: I tried 'ps' and 'w' and 'whoami' and 'echo'. They don't produce any output either. :-(

Comment: @JAmes: just to be sure. have you sent to the shell commands with `\n` on the end? Also please add your platform information.

Comment: yes, of course :-) Because they do work (like I said with "touch") and to exit I need to type "exit". I will try the pty approach (from the answer below) now and will post here if it's good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of programs change their behavior depending on whether or not they think they're talking to a terminal (tty), and the shell definitely does this this. Also, the default C streams `stdout` and `stderr` are probably unbuffered if `stdout` is a tty, and fully buffered otherwise - that means that they don't flush until the internal buffer is full, the program explicitly flushes them, or the program ends.

To work around this problem, you have to make your program pretend to be a terminal. To do this, you can use your system's pseudo-terminal APIs (try `man 7 pty`). The end result is a pair of file descriptors that sort-of work like a pipe.

Also, as an aside, when select unblocks, you should read exactly once from the triggered file descriptor. If you read more than once, which is possible with the loop you've got there, you risk blocking again on subsequent reads, unless you've got your FD in non-blocking mode.

However, I have to ask: why do you need to interact with the shell in this way? Is it possible to, say, just run a shell script, or use "/bin/sh -c your_command_here" instead? There are relatively few programs that actually need a real terminal to work correctly - the main ones are programs that prompt for a password, like `ssh`, `su` or `sudo`.

Comment: 1) I tried filling up the buffer by cat'ing big files, but nothing happens! 2) I am developing a rsh-like remote shell though a special hardware, but so I am not able to use sockets(its a complicated situation, I know). 3) Don't worry about the loop -- I need to read at least something!

Comment: Ah, OK, if you're doing something like rsh, then you should use the pseudo-terminal approach - that's how rsh and ssh work internally.